# Eclipse including Java source code files with class files in WAR

Tags: java, eclipse, war

When I choose the option to export my dynamic web project in Eclipse (Juno) as a WAR file, all of the .java files are being deployed to WEB-INF/classes along with the .class files.  I've never noticed this happening before, so I was wondering what I needed to do to stop this from happening.

Comment: Which Version of Eclipse you are running?

Comment: Juno - made edit to question.

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce this on Juno, however I noticed there is a checkbox named "Export source files" I assume you have it unchecked, but if not, then this might be it.

[image]

Comment: I did see that checkbox, but I have always left it unchecked.  The only ones checked are "Optimize for a specific server runtime" and "overwrite existing file".